# Android's custom status bar notification bug?

Tags: android, notifications, statusbar

I am trying to show a custom notification content on the status bar via Remote View.  I am using fill_parent for both width and height, but there is always a small gap on the right side.  What am I doing wrong here?

Please see the screen shot here: http://img684.imageshack.us/img684/2347/devicenq.png

Layout code (I also used LinearLayout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:background="@color/solid_yellow"
              >
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
              android:src="@drawable/stat_sample"
              />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:textColor="#000"
              android:text="Hello, this message is in a custom expanded view"
              />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the code snippet:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MessengerService.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
    this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.stat_sample,
    "Hello", System.currentTimeMillis());

RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
    R.layout.custom_notification_layout);

notification.contentView   = contentView;
notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;

mNM.notify(R.string.remote_service_started, notification);
```

I have been banging my head all day with this...
Thank you.

Comment: "I wish I can post the image, but I have less than 10 rep points..." -- upload it somewhere else and link to it.

Comment: Did you eventually resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You have a

```
 android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
```

and that's when this space on the right appears

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I removed it and the gap is still there.

Comment: Then give your TextView and ImageView a fill parent for their's width.

Comment: Isn't that going to stretch the the image?

Comment: then just do for the TextView. Also use a linearlayout. I think because of the way it will be layed out, if you defined the LinearLayout as horizontal orientation, give the ImageView a width of wrap_content and the TextView a width of fill_parent (this is the reason it was sort of renamed to match_parent) the text view will expand to the right and not collide with the ImageView.

Comment: you can use a 9patch for stretchable images, it may sound weird to you but it isn't a big deal, just to mark where exactly the image can be stretched:  http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

Comment: @sdfdfsfd I have used 9-patch before, but I need to place a text and an image.   9-patch solution would't work nicely here with many different dpi's.

Comment: Did anyone ever figure this out?  I am having the same issue.

Comment: I used an empty linearlayout and had the exact same result. Anyone?

Comment: Still haven't able to figure this out...  Just ended up removing the color and kept the original color.